# make make backdate timstamps on failed build

Tags: pdf, makefile, timestamp, pdflatex

BACKGRUND:
I often use `make` do build my latex documents, and have come across the following annoyance:
Let's say I want to build `file.pdf` using make as

```
.PHONY: all
all: file.pdf    

file.pdf: file.tex
    pdflatex file.tex
```

This works fine, and my `file.pdf` gets nicely updated when needed... until the latex build breaks. Now, the problem is that pdflatex - even if the build failed, leaves behind an updated pdf (and I want it that way). But since the broken build has left an updated pdf the next time I invoke `make`, nothing will happen.

My workaround for this is to have a separate target `.file.pdf` that gets updated after the `file.pdf` has been successfully built

```
.PHONY: all
all: .file.pdf    

.file.pdf: file.tex
    pdflatex file.tex
    touch .file.pdf
```

This solves the problem bus is ugly in the sense that it creates a new file that I don't want.

QUESTION:
Is there a way to tell make to simply reset (or otherwise backdate) the timestamps on `file.pdf` in case the build fails? This way the next run of `make` will find an outdated version of `file.pdf` and rebuild.

NB: I know there is an option to remove `file.pdf` if the build is broken, but I don't want that, because even thought the build broke, I want to be able to look at the pdf that was generated.

NB II: Before you ask why I don't just update the tex-code and re-run (since this solves the problem). I typically fix the problem in the tex-code before exiting the broken pdflatex build (I think this is quite common practice), so then when I rerun `make` the pdf will be younger than the fixed tex-file.

Comment: You can use [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) to remember the original timestamp, then if pdflatex failed, restore it using [touch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) command. Please remember, every line in body of Makefile rules is spawned in another shell. So, you need to do that as a one line.

Comment: If you use a `make`-driven build, wouldn't it be a better match to just have `pdflatex` exit on error, like typical compilers do, e.g. by using the `-interaction=nonstopmode` command line argument to `pdflatex`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks, I wasnt aware of the `-halt-on-error` and `-interaction=nonstopmode` options. For some reason they seem to have no effect on my system though!? But that an OS-specific problem and beyond the scope of this post.